# JS var declared outside <script> file for use in said file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of JS added to my home page like so-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var mm_home;
  mm_home = true;
</script>
```

I have another JS file that is being pulled into the head (below the above) that has the following lines:

```
baseUrl = $(this).parent().attr("action");

    if(mm_home) {
        url = baseUrl + 'category/bank-events/' + $('#tribe-events-events-year').val() + '-' + $('#tribe-events-events-month').val();
    } else {
        url = baseUrl + $('#tribe-events-events-year').val() + '-' + $('#tribe-events-events-month').val();
    }
```

However, when I view my home page, the above conditional is failing and it reverts to the 2nd url var when I want it to use the first.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How can you tell it's not working?  From what you posted, that second chunk of code would have no visible effect on the page. You're not even showing the definition of "url".

Comment: As it stands, the `if` will get executed because `mm_home` is true, or else you get a ReferenceError with regard to `mm_home` if the scripts are swapped. What value is `mm_home` in your failing case?

Comment: The reason I ask is that what you've posted would definitely work, barring some *other* code that's broken.  However, you've posted no other code.

Comment: That's it though @Pointy, it doesn't work.  What happens is a page redirection to the reference URI if someone makes a change to a select box.  I can tell it doesn't work because it redirects to the 2nd URI every time.

pimvdb there is no value for it otherwise, it isn't set in any other instance.

Comment: Here's the deal: including a script that declares a global variable before another script that examines the global variable **definitely** works. You haven't posted all the code - what's "url"?  Where *exactly* is that second code running?  A "ready" handler? An event handler? What happens to "url" after that point?

Comment: Have you tried changing the first script to "window.mm_home = true;" and the second to read window.mm_home?  Also, try putting console.log statements in both scripts to see that they execute in the order you think they do.  If both of those work out, then something must be changing mm_home in the meantime.

Comment: What do you get if you put `console.log(mm_home)` or `alert(mm_home)` just before the `if` statement?

Comment: @Pointy here's the full code of the JS file.  The code runs when someone modifies a select box selection. http://pastebin.com/UJFnvNtr

Comment: @nnnnnn Nothing happens. The page redirects to the "wrong" url and nothing alerts or gets recorded to console.

Comment: @AresAvatar adding the window. as part of the var name didn't change the behavior.  Still not working.  See my note above to Pointy for full source.

Comment: @Marty and what about the `console.log()` call?  This is something you should be able to get a lot of information about via the browser debugging tools and log calls.